# On Debian, what software/tool can I use to force a different font onto an application?

Tags: debian, font

I'm using this program Simplenote. Its a note-syncing online application.
My problem with it is that i write there a lot of numbers on multiple lines, but their font isn't monospace-type, so it doesn't align itself properly.
Is there any tool I can use to force any monospace font for this aplication only? 
The app itself doesnt allow any bulit-in font change.